# My laptop's performance has decreased a lot

Tags: windows-10, performance

I have a acer laptop. It is using windows 10 ,64bit,i3 7th gen processor ,8gb ram,nvidia geforce 940mx. It is just two months old. I am working with some heavy softwares like blender, I noticed that the performance of my system has decreased a lot in this time span. It takes longer time to star, hangs a lot what can i do to increase its performance

Comment: What kind of disk does it have?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare RAM slot try adding another RAM module. Make sure it matches the one already installed. If you have a spare slot you could increase the total RAM to 16GB. Your hard drive may not be a solid-state drive also. If it has spinning platter/s you could upgrade that to increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could cause this, but here are the first places to check:

### Programs eating CPU or RAM

Is something heavy running that you don't need? You can check with Task Manager. To open it, press Control, Shift, and Escape at the same time. On the first tab, Processes, you can sort the column by CPU, Memory, and a few other things. Check out what is using high CPU and what is using high RAM. If you don't recognize the software by name, check Google. There's a good bet that it's a Windows process and can't be closed. If you do recognize the software and it's using too many resources then close it until you need it again.

### Programs starting themselves on boot

Many programs will configure themselves up to start with Windows. They are wasting your computer's RAM and CPU resources. Some are harder to disable and must be configured from inside the app, but you can start by looking at the Startup tab in Task Manager. Go to the Startup tab. Rows that have Status "Enabled" will run every time Windows starts. Disable anything that you recognize and google whatever is left, you can probably turn them off too. Check the icons on the Windows taskbar. These are also running programs that can usually be closed and configured to not start with Windows via a setting somewhere in the opened version of the program. An example of one app that works this way is Adobe Creative Cloud.

### Thermal problems

Is your laptop running hot? I recommend a program called [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/specc). (Be warned, though, when you install it make sure the parent company didn't sneak any extra software in with the installer.) It can show you all sorts of hardware info. Take a look at the processor and GPU temperature graphs. (You can click the little green box to expand them into full graphs.) Are they higher than 80C? Laptops run hot but anything higher than that indicates that you're either running something intense or something is wrong with the computer's cooling system. Things like dust blocking airflow, bad fans, or bad thermal paste.

Please take a look through these things and report back if nothing jumps out as obviously wrong.

Comment: I tried all those things but neither there are any ram/cpu eating programs or any heavy programs loading booting but i noticed that the temperature of my cpu increases from 40°C to around 60°C when I try to render some of the heavy animations could it be a reason?

Comment: Is it only slow when rendering? That is normal. Laptops get hot when they're working hard. Desktops usually are less effected.

Comment: It's slow during rendering , and it works slowly until I restart it, after restart it works somewhat better

Comment: I wanted to buy a desktop for the same reason but under some conditions i had to buy a laptop

Comment: Could it just be cooling down? Past that... Some vendors include software than can control power settings, like a Quiet Mode or a Performance Mode. Look up your model and see if they have one. That changes the fan settings and power limits on the CPU. There are also the Windows settings to try. One way uses a slider to change power settings, that's in the battery icon in the task bar. There is also a Control Panel version. Use the Windows button, type "Edit power plan", open it then click "Change advanced power settings". The top dropdown changes the mode, try "Power Saver"